# Inner Join и вопрос по предикату

Tags: sql, postgresql

Оператор левого внешнего соединения LEFT OUTER JOIN соединяет две таблицы. Порядок таблиц для оператора важен, поскольку оператор не является коммутативным.

Заголовок таблицы-результата является объединением (конкатенацией) заголовков соединяемых таблиц.

Тело результата логически формируется следующим образом. Пусть выполняется соединение левой и правой таблиц по предикату (условию) p.

В результат включается внутреннее соединение (INNER JOIN) левой и правой таблиц по предикату p.
Затем в результат добавляются те строки левой таблицы, которые не вошли во внутреннее соединение на шаге 1. Для таких строк столбцы, соответствующие правой таблице, заполняются значениями NULL.

> Пусть выполняется соединение левой и правой таблиц по предикату
>   (условию) p.

По предикату (условию) p? Что за p? по предикату?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предикаты представляют собой выражения, принимающие истинностное значение. Т е это условия для фильтрации запросов.

> Пусть выполняется соединение левой и правой таблиц по предикату
>   (условию) p.

Пример.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

Для данного запросв предикат(p) это `table1.column_name = table2.column_name`

Comment: А что за p? почему не x?не u? и тд?)

Comment: predicate первая буква

Comment: спасибо братик <3